# Can't add PHP extension "mssql.so"

Tags: apache-http-server, php, ms-sql, php.ini, php-extensions

I want to add mssql.so extension to my PHP.

I've already put it in the extension_dir and the line "extension=mssql.so" is in my `php.ini`. I restarted apache but I can't find the extension in `phpinfo();` …

Historically, there are NO other extensions for PHP. It was a rule in my company but I have to change that.

Is there something in the `httpd.conf` or in `php.ini` that I have to change? Or a setting to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Does anything obvious pop out in apache's error.log?

The comments at [the php.net page on mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php) seem to indicate a dependency on unixODBC; do you have that package loaded?  Or, if you're in Win32, the latest MDAC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I can see the line: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect()", I could guess that there would be such an output... unixODBC isn't loaded, the tutorial I followed doesn't mention it (http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/01/adding-support-for-ms-sql-server-to-php-in-linux/)... I have to check why the extension is not loaded...